# Registration form validating errors

Tags: php, mysql

If I submit blank fields it still adds it into database. I made a loop to check if everything is on place but it keeps redirecting it to error page. I've been struggling with this almost 2 hours but cant find a solution.
Links are [here](http://pastebin.com/ppmKZ8vh) since i can post more than 2 :

Answer (score 0):

Try to set

> Don't allow nulls

in the column property of table. It can be done during the table design or Edit table Design in the database.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You using empty().  https://www.php.net/empty
This only returns false if NULL, FALSE, or not exists, NOT if empty string.

You should be doing this:

```
foreach($required as $post){
    if ($_POST[$post] == "") {
        die(header("refresh:0.5;url=error.php"));
    }
}
```

However, I don't know why you don't just put this over the entire code block so it only gets executed on submit of the form.  Then you don't have to keep rechecking it.

```
if (isset($_POST)) { //or a specific $_POST variable if multiple submit paths
    //code here
}
```

Additionally, you should edit your question to include the relevant code in the question or in the future, searchers may discover that your pastebin link no longer works.

Answer (score 0):

I think in any way you should make some client-side validation on empty field like jQuery functions :

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        $("form").submit(function(){
            if($("#first_name").val() == ''){
                alert("First name cann't be empty");
                return false;
            }else if($("#last_name").val() == ''){
                alert("Last name cann't be empty");
                return false;   
            }else if($("#email").val() == ''){
                alert("Email cann't be empty");
                return false;   
            }else if($("#password").val() == ''){
                alert("Password name cann't be empty");
                return false;   
            }            
        });
    });                
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to get indexes on **$_POST** array that doesn't exist, so correct your **$required** array and put fields names not the variables names, just like this in **process.php**:

```
$required = array('first_name','last_name','password','email');
foreach($required as $post){
    if($post = empty($_POST[$post]) || $_POST[$post] == ""){
        die(header("refresh:0.5;url=error.php"));
    } elseif($required != empty($_POST)) {
        echo "";
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I think yor a looking for something like,

```
if(isset($_POST['field1']) && !$_POST['field1'] =="")
{
//your codes goes here

}
```

Maybe You have done something like

```
<input type=text name=name1 value ="" />
```

If so, Please do it like,

```
<input type=text name=name1 />
```

This will not send name1 to your page;

Comment: It's not about a _value_ attribute, but he's trying to get an _undefined _ index on **$_POST** array, this is why his test for empty  data gives him always true and redirects to error.php page whatever he put in the form as values.